# MySQL - Which way is better to check if a column is null or empty

Tags: mysql, isnull

Well, when we are going to select records which include nothing in a column, we can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE NULLIF(my_column, '') IS NULL;
```

But, in most cases, I see developers use this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column IS NULL OR my_column = ''
```

Is there any preference between these two? (e.g. performance, default support, version support, etc.)

If yes, please explain.

Comment: I'm kinda thinking you should change accepted answer to Solarflare's. Mine deals with the function vs `OR` case; their answer gives a definitive reason why `... IS NULL OR ...` is superior.

Comment: @Uueerdo, Generous and Gentle ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluating the two expressions on a single row should not take such a big difference. The reason people use the second version is the use of indexes. Mysql has a special optimization for this and can use it even with the `or`.

See [IS NULL Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/is-null-optimization.html)

> **IS NULL Optimization**
>
> MySQL can perform the same optimization on col_name IS NULL that it can use for col_name = constant_value. For example, MySQL can use indexes and ranges to search for NULL with IS NULL.
>
> If a WHERE clause includes a col_name IS NULL condition for a column that is declared as NOT NULL, that expression is optimized away. This optimization does not occur in cases when the column might produce NULL anyway; for example, if it comes from a table on the right side of a LEFT JOIN.
>
> MySQL can also **optimize the combination col_name = expr OR col_name IS NULL**, a form that is common in resolved subqueries. EXPLAIN shows ref_or_null when this optimization is used.

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge best way with respect to execution time or performance is :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column = ''
```

Reference : [How do I check if a column is empty or null in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470813/how-do-i-check-if-a-column-is-empty-or-null-in-mysql)

Comment: I couldn't find any performance comparison in the post you linked

Comment: Nevertheless, as I said in my Answer above, "Naveed's solution is **obvious** to anyone who looks at it." And that "wins the game, in my book, every single time." I'm not really concerned about microseconds. But, I really am concerned about *clarity.* I don't want a *human* reader to have to go scrambling for the MySQL documentation *(as I did ...)* to figure out what this statement means, and to ensure that it is actually doing what I think it does and what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a function on a field (in a condition) automatically discards any potential indexes on that field that could be used to speed up the query. Using `OR` in a list of conditions generally does the same (but for all indexes).

However, with the former, you end up making a function call for every row; with the latter there is the possibility to take advantage of short circuit evaluation.

Of course, there is a third option which can make use of indexes...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column IS NULL
UNION
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column = ''
```

but then the cost of the UNION/two queries may outweigh the benefit of index use; depending on actual data.

Comment: It's an interesting question whether the query-optimizer can "optimize away" `NULLIF()` and not *actually* handle it as a true function-call. (Would it instead replace it with a `CASE` as the documentation suggests? It *could...)* ## I'm not "comfortable at first glance" that your `UNION`-based alternative would really work, *and* simply "would rather not have to take a second or third glance figure out if it actually does or not."  I daresay that the query optimizer *would* be smart-enough to use indexes.  So, I'd rather see "simple" than "clever."  *But,* "that's just me."

Comment: The UNION-based alternative is always my very last choice as it results in almost duplicating a query (which can be worse than actually duplicating it), however I can confirm from experience that MySQL will not optimize OR clauses to have the same benefit. _It's applicability also becomes less likely as the full set of conditions becomes more complicated, which may be why MySQL does not try to optimize it in a similar manner._ @MikeRobinson

Answer (score 1):

The two constructs are not the same.  From [the MySQL documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif):

```
NULLIF(expr1,expr2)

Returns NULL if expr1 = expr2 is true, otherwise returns expr1. 
This is the same as:
  CASE WHEN expr1 = expr2 
  THEN NULL 
  ELSE expr1 
  END.
```

Therefore, this logic is testing a column for "`NULL` *or* an empty string."

- If `my_column` is presently NULL, the function will return its value (NULL ...) because it is not equal to an empty-string.
- If `my_column` *is* an empty string, the function will return NULL.
- If any other value, that value will be returned.

I heartily agree with Naveed's answer in saying, *"this is 'cute' ... don't be 'cute'."* His answer ("use `OR` ...") results in very simple SQL that is instantly *obvious* at first glance.  This "clever" solution is not. (And it is probably slightly-less efficient, to boot.)

And, of course, you'd really like to *avoid* the necessity for this sort of thing when designing your database. You never want to store "empty strings" in a VARCHAR-type field unless it truly *is* the case that "we have a non-NULL value, and that value *really is* 'an empty string.'"

Comment: Got it. About your last paragraph, I'm not always the one who designs the DB from the scratch. sometimes, I face to a table with millions of records and I'm not allowed to change the structure. BTW, thanks for your explanation

Comment: I don't know if I'd call it "being cute". In this particular context it seems like overkill, but in a larger set of conditions (with potentially numerous checks like this) using this form _(or `IFNULL(x, '') = '')_ could make the query more readable. ...and the guys who have to "read" the data are not always the ones that write it.

Comment: Oh, yes, Mojtaba, *that* "is the state of the real world!"  **:-)** We *all* have to deal with databases containing millions of records that *"are* as they are."

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the reason why people will include the ='' portion is because SQL Server stores that as an empty string, which is not the same as NULL.

Link to reference: 
[openshac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618357/sql-server-null-vs-empty-string)

Comment: I know that. Both of the queries I put do the same. My question is which one is better?

Comment: I would include both. It's not going to cost you much on performance, and this way you ensure it is doing what you want.